# Creating a summary column in SAS from multiple columns

Tags: arrays, sas

I want to create a single column in SAS that summarizes several columns for each individual in a data set. The data looks like the following:

```
Subject      VisitNumber   Exam      Result       Comments
001          1             Blood     Negative     Will return for more testing
001          1             BP        100          Score is in normal range
001          1             Vision    20/20        No issues with eyesight 
002          5             BMI       19           Within healthy range
002          5             Hearing   Good         Patient hears well
002          5             Drug      Negative     Subject passed drug test
```

The information for each subject and their subsequent visit number should be summarized like this:

```
Subject    VisitNumber      Summary
001        1                Exam: Blood, Result: Negative, Comments: Will return for more testing; Exam: BP, Result: 100, Comments: Score is normal range; Exam: Vision, Result: 20/20, Comments: No issues with eyesight
002        5                Exam: BMI, Result: 19, Comments: Within healthy range; Exam: Hearing, Result: Good, Comments: Patient hears well; Exam: Drug, Result: Negative, Comments: Subject passed drug test
```

Can do this in R the following way:

```
for (i in 1:length(data$Subject))

{
data$Summary[i] = data$Comments[i] = 'Exam: ' + Exam[i] + ', Result: ' + Result[i] + ', Comments: ' + Comments[i] + '; '
}
```

Data could then be compressed row wise by Comments column. Any insight as to how this can be done via the DATA or PROC SQL step in SAS would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SAS concatenate functions.

```
data want;
   set have;
   by subject notsorted;
   length summary $500.;
   retain summary;
   summary=catx(';',summary, catx(',', cats('Exam:',Exam),cats('Result:',Result),cats('Comments:',Comments)));
   if last.subject then output;
   keep Subject VisitNumber summary;
run;
```

Comment: I think you're missing a statement to set SUMMARY to null at the beginning of each by group.  Something like: `if first.subject then summary='' ;`  So that values are not retained across subjects.

Comment: @Quentin Adding first.subject then summary = '' solves the issue of values being retained across groups. However, if a subject only has one row, then that value is deleted. Any way to retain the first.subject and have it not carry over?

Comment: @statsguyz add it immediately after the retain statement.  Before the assignment statement that assigns summary.

Answer (score 2):

For reporting purposes `Proc PRINT` has a special output layout when the `BY` and `ID` statements list the same variables names.  The groups will be *separated* and the group's values will *not repeat* when the group has more than one row.

```
data have;
input
Subject&$    VisitNumber&  Exam&$    Result&$     Comments&$200.; datalines;
001          1             Blood     Negative     Will return for more testing
001          1             BP        100          Score is in normal range
001          1             Vision    20/20        No issues with eyesight 
002          5             BMI       19           Within healthy range
002          5             Hearing   Good         Patient hears well
002          5             Drug      Negative     Subject passed drug test
run;

ods html style=Journal;
title "Subject visit examinations";
proc print data=have;
  by subject visitnumber;
  id subject visitnumber;
run;
```

[image]